# Maven copy local files into top-level m2 library folder or equivalent effect

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

is there a way to specify in `pom.xml` to copy certain local files to some third-party library staging folder downloaded in ~/.m2 to achieve the effect of packaging the Maven app along with these files in the specified folder. This is necessary because the aforementioned library depends on some native compiled code. If not possible or too dirty, how to achieve the same effect in a Maven-friendly manner? Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried `maven-install-plugin` in my `pom.xml` like this

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <file>${basedir}/z3-4.8.8-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/z3</file>
<!--                    how ???-->
<!--                    <file>${basedir}/z3-4.8.8-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/libz3java.so</file>-->
<!--                    <file>${basedir}/z3-4.8.8-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/libz3.so</file>-->
<!--                    <file>${basedir}/z3-4.8.8-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/libz3.a</file>-->
                    <groupId>org.sosy_lab</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-smt</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

, but my questions is how to include multiple files?

Comment: Maybe with the `install:install-file` goal of the Maven Install Plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Thanks. But I want to install stuff into the global Maven directory, not my local project repository.

Comment: `${user.home}/.m2/repository` is the default location of the *local repository*. Is this what you call "global Maven directory"? I'm not aware of a "local project repository". If you are refering to a *remote repository* you could check Maven Deploy Plugin.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I tried it. It seems to work but how do I do multiple files/an entire directory (and subdirectories)? The default configuration only supports one `<file>` attribute.

Comment: I believe you would have to do it for every file individually. I recommend you to update your question to show what you have so far and, if you come up with a solution, include it too.